# How to attach other supporting setup file into my application during making setup file?

Tags: c#

i want to attach .net frame work setup file into my setup file and more other so that my application will run in other PC? what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Use Visual Studio to create a "Setup Project". It will handle installing the requisite version of the .NET Framework automatically. Google for details. Don't make this any more difficult than it needs to be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean using an include file?

Like the **file attribute** in the [appSettings Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx) or the [SectionInformation.ConfigSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx)?

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="machine-specific.config">
        <add key="Application Name" value="MyApplication" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```