# SMTP config environment variable pickupdirectorylocation

Tags: c#, smtp, config

I am trying to use an environment variable in SMTP config for the specified pickup directory location. E.g.

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="test@test.com">
  <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="%TESTFOLDER%"/>
</smtp>


"%TESTFOLDER% = C:\Test
```

But getting back an error saying the path must be absolute.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?  Or even if it's possible!

Comment: Are you saying that your config file contains `"%TESTFOLDER%"` as the value?

Comment: why dont you write "c:\test" into the attribute value itself ??

Comment: @Furqan: I guess @BlueChippy wants machine-specific configuration (config include files are better suited for that IMHO).

Comment: @NeilKnight - Yes, I wanted to put the environment variable into the config file, so that when we moved from server to server, the mail pickup would always be correct.  This is because all of our servers have different numbers of HDD's, so the pickup folder is in a different location (mad, I know, but I have to work with it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use it like that.

What you can do is set the name of the env. variable in your app.settings and then set the [pickupDirectoryLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.configuration.smtpspecifiedpickupdirectoryelement.pickupdirectorylocation.aspx) in code using the [System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx).

Or loose the env. variable completely and use a [config file include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217713/how-to-attach-other-supporting-setup-file-into-my-application-during-making-setup/5217796#5217796) (preferred).

Comment: Used the config file include in the end.  Thx